# How to map the line numbers from compiled jsp classes to the original source code?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, stack-trace

My question is about how to troubleshoot exceptions in compiled jsp classes.

Example: I got the following stack trace from the production system (running on Apache Tomcat):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jspc_compiled.infobox_jsp._jspService(infobox_jsp.java:147)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
```

Via the version control I can restore the original Java files and JSP files from the released version. I also have access to the deployed war file. **What I did not found, is a reliable way to map the line numbers from the exception in the compiled JSP back to the original source code.**

Is there a good way to analyze stacktraces in compiled JSPs from another machine?

Related side-question: Is it guaranteed that if I compile the JSPs on my local machine (with the identical version of the source code) that the compiled JSPs will be exactly the same as on the other machine?

Comment: what ide do you use for dev?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy I mostly use IDEA but also Eclipse. When I develop locally I have no problem identifying the line of the exception. My problem is only if I just get the stacktrace and the version number of the software.

Answer (score 1):

In [Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_can_I_debug_with_the_Java_source_that_Tomcat_creates_for_a_JSP.3F) we can debug with the Java source that Tomcat creates for a JSP

Comment: Yes, when I run the application locally, I am able to debug it. The difficult part that I have not yet figured out is how to analyze a problem that cannot be reproduced locally but where you only have a stack trace.